# MSSQL After Update Trigger: Multi Row Stored Prc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I've written a stored procedure which I would like to invoke on row updates.

It could look something like this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [TraceChange]
    @Id uniqueidentifier,
AS
BEGIN
    /*do some inserts, updates, etc*/
END
```

Now I create a trigger for a Table, which works fine for a single row update:

```
Create TRIGGER T1_TraceInsert
   on T1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @id uniqueidentifier
    exec TraceChange @id
END
```

This works fine - but just for a single Row.
How do I rewrite it to execute on **multi row updates**?
AFAIK its not a great approach to use a cursor within such triggers.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, inline the stored-proc and re-write it to be set-based rather than row-based. But is such a transformation viable? Impossible to tell here without knowing what the stored proc actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1) Process the data in while loop - get the data from **inserted** table, and execute your SP X times - one per row.

2) Rewrite SP (or create a new one) which accepts table as input parameter. Process all the rows in one go if possible.  Depends on the code of SP. So, in the trigger, you execute that SP and pass some predefined table which is based on **inserted** table

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx with example.

Comment: Table Parameters is the way to go here. Thanks.